# Find files which have (or have not) a specific owner

Tags: linux, bash

How to find files in a specific directory (and sub folders - recursive) that have a specific owner name or that have not a specified owner name in the search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the find command.

```
find (directory) -user (user)
find (directory) -not -user (user)
```

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-all-the-files-owned-by-a-particular-user-or-group/

Comment: Or `find /some/directory '!' -user 'username'` using `'!'` instead of `-not`.  If you aren't using Bash, you don't need to quote the `!` — the C shell is so uncivilized, and it was so unnecessary to import that into Bash.